A systematic way to derive truth tables
Is there any procedure (not a brute-force one) that can give me a desires logical gate/operator from a given set of gates/operators?
Example:
In order to get the Multiplexer gate, one does $Mul(A,B,S_0)=\left ( A\wedge \neg S_0 \right )\vee\left ( B\wedge S_0 \right )$
Let's say I received the truth table of $Mul(A,B,S_0)$.
My question is there exists a better way to get $\left ( A\wedge \neg S_0 \right )\vee\left ( B\wedge S_0 \right )$ rather then listing all the possible combination of $A,B,S_0$ with the gates/operators $\wedge ,\vee, \neg$ (which can of course give me any truth table) and hoping for the best.
In other words, is there any procedure to go from $$\begin{matrix} S_0 &A &B &Z \\ 0& 0& 0&0 \\ 0& 0& 1&0 \\ 0& 1& 0&1 \\ 0& 1& 1&1 \\ 1& 0& 0&0 \\ 1& 0& 1&1 \\ 1& 1& 0&0 \\ 1& 1& 1&1 \end{matrix}$$
to $Z=\left ( A\wedge \neg S_0 \right )\vee\left ( B\wedge S_0 \right )$

Have you heard about conjunctive normal form (CNF) and disjunctive normal form (DNF)?

@Vasili Hello, yes.

That's one way to build a formula using the truth table. You may also look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation

Please correct me if I wrong, but in CNF and DNF and Tseytin transformation you are given a formula, and you use methods to get an equivalent formula with a specific form.
What I'm asking I think is a bit different:
I'm giving you a truth table that consist of the variables and a column that represent what I want the operator to do.
What are you doing in order to give me a CNF / DNF formula ?

Maybe I don't quite get what you need. It sounded like you wanted to find a formula given a truth table.

"It sounded like you wanted to find a formula given a truth table" - This is right, but I only have the truth table, nothing else.

Do you consider looking at a big "or" whose entries are big "ands" specifying exactly the true rows of your table to be "brute force"? For example, in two variables if you're trying to build something with the same truth table as $p \to q$ you can just write $$(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q).$$ In general you can do $$\bigvee_{\text{true assignments}} \left ( x_1^\pm \land \cdots \land x_n^\pm \right )$$ where the $\pm$ is meant to indicate you either have $x_i$ or $\lnot x_i$ depending on what makes the assignment true.

If you don't consider this brute force, then I can leave it as an answer, and relate it to some other interesting math

You can check out Karnaugh maps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

@TankutBeygu This post is clearly not talking about the post you linked. As I mentioned in the comments, that task is to build a formula with a given truth table, not with a given formula. You can see the truth table of Mul in the link in the post, but I added it any way. The comment about Karnaugh maps is the topic I was looking for. Please cancel your downvote.

My comment was about that the question is a duplicate, so it should be closed.  Since there are lots of questions related to Karnaugh maps that can be browsed by the search utility, I thought, as some others, something else was sought. As you say, it is a duplicate, indeed.

@TankutBeygu I couldn't search it, because the first time I heard about it was in the comments of this post. I didn't say nothing about a duplicate.

@Daniel one doesn't need to know the name. Try, for instance, "how to simplify logic gate."

This question is similar to: Tseytin transformation example. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
